# creating thumb from large file on php

Tags: php, gd, thumbnails, fatal-error

I need to create thumbs from uploaded file(jpg, gif, png). 
I am using GD for it.

And when try to create thumb from uploaded file that is large(1262x16482) - I get fatal error 
**Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 60126336 bytes)**
on line
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);

I've tried to find answers on this issues and most of them are about increasing memory_limit in php.ini.
For some reasons this solutions doesn't suit me.

Maybe there are some php extensions that allow to read not all file into memory, but only some part of it.

Comment: If you tried to increase memory_limit, but it didn't work, then it is being overlapped somewhere later in program flow.

Comment: Keep in mind that this might affect the performance of your page if users allowed to create thumbnails from very large images. If the size you mention isn't a typo (16482 pixels!) it's not so weird PHP is running out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of file it may be *mandatory* to load the whole thing into memory before doing work on it.

Most graphics file formats don't store the info in a linear format. Rather the data in one section may refer to some structure in another section or vv. Your best bet would be to either up your allowed memory in php.ini or limit the file size at upload time.

Answer (score 0):

I think the use of TimThumb will be easier for you since you may be have some wrong actions 
http://code.google.com/p/timthumb/

All you needs to download it and call the images throw it.